# store an array of all the terms existing

Tags: terms

How can I store an array of all the terms existing? (for admin use)

```
$taxonomy = 'MYTAXONOMY'; 
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy); 
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {     
      echo  $tax_term->slug ; 
    }
```

seems to only work from template files, but I would like to store this array in functions.php for using in a tinyMCE select box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is, you're practically there! You can use your code anywhere (as long as it's after the `init` hook), not just in template files.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'MYTAXONOMY' );
$term_slugs = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );
```

[`wp_list_pluck()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck) is a very cool little function that will pluck a field out of an array of arrays/objects & return it as a single array:

```
print_r( $term_slugs ); // Array( 'slug_1', 'slug_2', ... )
```